# appcompat values-v21\themes_base.xml errors

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I had already created a project and it worked fairly well.
It occurred to me download the SDK 5.0.1 and tried to make a new activity on that project that worked well and gives me among others the following error:

appcompat_v7 \ res \ values-v21 \ themes_base.xml: 195: error: Error: No resource found That matches the given name: attr 'android: colorControlHighlight'.

All errors are the same stilo of graphic elements.

How I can fix it?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your appcompat v7 library folder, you will find project.properties file

in that add/replace these lines. either just change the target to 21. This Worked for me

```
target=android-21
android.library=true
```

clean rebuild the project